# Index sources files into a standalone source server without TFS 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, version-control, debug-symbols, symstore

I have a solution, which is built using Visual Studio 2010 from a command line. After build, a  `symstore` from Debugging Tools for Windows is invoked to post PDBs and binaries to the network folder, which is then used as a symbol store.

I understand there also is a Source Server, which I could use together with Symbol Store to keep the source files. How do I have the source files added to that symbol store? I see there is a `srcsrv` directory in Debugging Tools, but I cannot find a way to create a source server system outside existing source control system using those tools

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically you do not add the source files to the symbol store, instead you reference them in your source control systemm, and use [Windows Source Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680641%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to pull them down as needed (just like it does with the symbols).

You must run a script on the source files to add info to the pdbs, this info contains which version of the files were used and is than used later when you debug to get them.

Comment: Could you elaborate on how such a script would look? Or perhaps link to a msbuild task that accomplishes this?